# How to transfer the token from one test suite from another suite in SOAP UI?

Tags: ui-automation

How to transfer the token from one test suite to another suite in SOAP UI?

I'm expecting that the token transferred from one suite to another suite

Choose the source as **Properties** and property as **Property_Zipcode**. Do the same in the target section. Choose **Target_Property** from the property drop-down. When run icon, the property value will be transferred from **Property_Zipcode** to **Target_Property**.